# using functools with IronPython

Tags: python, ironpython

I'm using the functools library with IronPython.

It works fine on the development machine, but in production the library can't be imported. Exception is thrown:

> IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException: No module named
>   _functools

IronPython is installed on the production machine of course and functools.py is there, but how should I deploy _functools?

Comment: According to the [doc](https://ironpython-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/functools.html), the functools package have been introduced in version 2.5. Which is your version ?

Comment: I'm using 2.7 and functools.py exists in the lib dir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally `_functools` is the native component that `functools.py` wraps. Given that native modules are not supported in IronPython (as of now) the relevant functionality is implemented in `IronPython.Modules.dll` (as seen [here](https://github.com/IronLanguages/main/blob/c5c192bc4c5c136da639017be83be00f94f5958f/Languages/IronPython/IronPython.Modules/_functools.cs)).

`IronPython.Modules.dll` is probably what you are missing.

Comment: Just copying the dll to the working directory fixed it, thanks!