# IronPython 2.7.8 encoding (ASCII) vs Python's 3.7 (UTF-8)

Tags: c#, python, encoding, ironpython

I need to use a Python library in my C# project. I've installed the IronPython (version 2.7.8) NuGet to my project and I've got this C# code:

```
1. var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
2. 
3. var paths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
4. paths.Add(@"C:\path\to\my\Python\standard\library\Lib");
5. engine.SetSearchPaths(paths);
6.
7. dynamic d = engine.ExecuteFile(@"path\to\python\library.py");
8. dynamic x = d.CallSomePythonLibraryFunction();
```

The problem is, the Python library (which I need to use) depends on some Python standard library functions. So I added search path to Python of version 2.7.12 (on line 4), after which I am getting this error:

```
IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException: 'No module named _functools'
```

(_functools is being imported from functools.py (if I understand it correctly, I am completely new to Python)).

I couldn't overcome this problem at all, so I tried to use another version of Python (the newest 3.7), with which I am getting this error:

```
Microsoft.Scripting.SyntaxErrorException: 'Non-ASCII character '\xc5' in file C:\Python37\Lib\functools.py on line 8, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details'
```

Now I know I have to change the encoding from default Python's 2.x ASCII (which IronPython uses?!) to Python's 3.x default UTF-8, but I wasn't able to figure how could I do that. I tried adding these lines of code ...

```
var script = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(@"import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')");
script.Execute();
```

... but it didn't help.

Comment: I don't think you can use IronPython 2.7.8 with CPython3, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37541483/5320906) looks like a solution for the `_functools` problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, I must have missed this answer. After applicating the provided solution I was getting another error: __future__ module was unable to load. I solved it with calling Python.CreateEngine().Runtime.LoadAssembly(Assembly.LoadFile(@"path\to\IronPythonModules.dll")).